# Regex Error Finding Details from a bank statement

Tags: python-3.x, python-re

I am working with Regex and currently I am trying to extract the Name, IFSC and Account No. from the PDF.
I am using following code to extract the details.

```
acc_name= " ", '\n'.join([re.sub(r'^[\d \t]+|[\d \t]+:$', '', line) for line in data.splitlines() if 'Mr. ' in line])
acc_no= " ", '\n'.join([re.sub(r'Account Number\s+:', '', line) for line in data.splitlines() if 'Account Number' in line])
acc_code = " ", '\n'.join([re.sub(r'IFSC Code\s+:', '', line) for line in data.splitlines() if 'IFSC Code' in line])
```

But the data which I am getting back is following:

```
(' ', ' 50439602642')
(' ', 'Mr. MOHD AZFAR ALAM LARI')
(' ', ' ALLA0211993')
```

I want to remove the commas, brackets and quotes. I am new with regex so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You are writing `" ", ...` which makes the tuple (the commas and brackets are part of the tuples string representation)... Also see [What are tags, and how should I use them?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) Please don't add tags that are not related to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're creating a tuple:

```
>>> " ", "\n'
(" ", "\n')
>>>
```

As you can see, a tuple is created, so either you mean by:

```
acc_name= ' \n'.join([re.sub(r'^[\d \t]+|[\d \t]+:$', '', line) for line in data.splitlines() if 'Mr. ' in line])
acc_no= ' \n'.join([re.sub(r'Account Number\s+:', '', line) for line in data.splitlines() if 'Account Number' in line])
acc_code = ' \n'.join([re.sub(r'IFSC Code\s+:', '', line) for line in data.splitlines() if 'IFSC Code' in line])
```

Or just a space:

```
acc_name= ' '.join([re.sub(r'^[\d \t]+|[\d \t]+:$', '', line) for line in data.splitlines() if 'Mr. ' in line])
acc_no= ' '.join([re.sub(r'Account Number\s+:', '', line) for line in data.splitlines() if 'Account Number' in line])
acc_code = ' '.join([re.sub(r'IFSC Code\s+:', '', line) for line in data.splitlines() if 'IFSC Code' in line])
```